# Understanding Reduction Problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, np-complete

I am having troubles understanding the concept of reduction and its relation with complexity.

I have defined some problems as follows:

- BreakRSA: From $(n = pq, e)$ find $d$ such that $ed = 1 \mod φ(n)$
- CDH: From $A = g^a$ and $B = g^b$ in a group, find $C = g^{ab}$
- DLOG: From $(g, g^x)$ from a group $G$ find $x ∈ {1, . . . , |G|}$
- ModExp: From $(x, n, e)$ integers compute $x^e \mod n$
- IntegerFact: From $n = pq$ an integer, find $p$ and $q$

From these I am trying to find all the problems such that `Prob1` is reductible to `Prob2`.

What I suggested is that:

- BreakRSA $\leq$ IntegerFact
- IntegerFact $\leq$ BreakRSA
- CDH $\leq$ DLOG

My question is if there are any other problems that can be reductible to others.

For instance I am doubting that:

- DLOG $\leq$ ModExp

Because by simply exponentiating all the $g$ to the power of $x ∈ {1, . . . , |G|}$ I can eventually find my $x$ (bruteforce attack). However my friend told me that it is not reductible because the bruteforce attack is not polynomial time (not P but NP).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: g a generator of the group ?

Comment: yes @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: Then you can go through at most half of all x values.

Comment: So that mean the algo is NP and we don't have DLOG ≤ ModExp right ? @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: The reason for halving is $$g^{\vert G\vert\over 2}\equiv -1\pmod m$$